# shell cmd failed while building rtems on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, shell, rtems

I was trying to build RTEMS using RTEMS Source Builder on a linux mint 17.02 system.I am getting shell cmd failed errors i.e(the last few lines of the error report )

```
+ cd /home/sambeet/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/rtems-tools-4.11-1
+ echo => rtems-tools-4.11-1:
+ echo ==> %prep:
+ pwd
+ build_top=/home/sambeet/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/rtems-tools-4.11-1
+ rtems_tools_source=rtems-tools-4.11
+ cd /home/sambeet/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/rtems-tools-4.11-1
+ /bin/rm -rf rtems-tools-4.11
+ ln -s /home/sambeet/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/sources/git/rtems-tools.git
+ cd rtems-tools-4.11
/home/sambeet/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/rtems-tools-4.11-1/doit: 85: cd: can't cd to rtems-tools-4.11
shell cmd failed: /bin/sh -ex  /home/sambeet/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/rtems-tools-4.11-1/doit
error: building rtems-tools-4.11-1
```

we can see that

**85: cd: can't cd to rtems-tools-4.11**

But on using cd through terminal we can do it..

```
sambeet@Holmes ~/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build $ ls
expat-2.1.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
rtems-tools-4.11-1
sparc-rtems4.11-binutils-2.24-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
sparc-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
sparc-rtems4.11-gdb-7.9-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
tmp
sambeet@Holmes ~/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build $ clear

sambeet@Holmes ~/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build $ ls
expat-2.1.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
rtems-tools-4.11-1
sparc-rtems4.11-binutils-2.24-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
sparc-rtems4.11-gcc-4.9.3-newlib-2.2.0.20150423-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
sparc-rtems4.11-gdb-7.9-x86_64-linux-gnu-1
tmp
sambeet@Holmes ~/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build $ cd rtems-tools-4.11-1/
sambeet@Holmes ~/development/rtems/src/rtems-source-builder/rtems/build/rtems-tools-4.11-1 $
```

Can anyone please provide an explanation or solution to this error?

Answer (score 1):

This - I believe - is a current issue with the RTEMS Source Builder.

Could you please try the patch in https://devel.rtems.org/ticket/2495 ?

If that works, then it'll be sorted soon (and thanks for the report!).

Just a suggestion, too, but RTEMS is something of a niche OS (being an RTOS, after all), so it might be more productive to post to users@rtems.org :-)

Edit: This is now fixed (see https://git.rtems.org/rtems-source-builder/commit/?id=7cdec5c335e0fe3d1a1bfd6e750890dc65b2d60f, thanks Patrick!), please update your RSB

Answer (score -1):

Basically the directory **rtems-tools-4.11** doesn't exist for some reason. So the script can't change to this directory. You can see that in the line:

**cd: can't cd to rtems-tools-4.11**